# Could not add addView in android

Tags: android, android-graphview

I need help friends.

Here is my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    float values[] = { 700, 400, 100, 500, 600 };
    float values1[] = { 70, 40, 10, 50 };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout lv1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);

        values = calculateData(values);
        values1 = calculateData(values1);
        MyGraphview graphview = new MyGraphview(this, values);
        graphview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        lv1.addView(graphview, 0);
        MyGraphview1 graphview1 = new MyGraphview1(this, values1);
        graphview1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        lv1.addView(graphview1, 0);

    }

    private float[] calculateData(float[] data) {
        float total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            total += data[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = 360 * (data[i] / total);
        }
        return data;
    }

    public class MyGraphview extends View {
        private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        private float[] value_degree;
        RectF rectf = new RectF(150, 150, 350, 350);

        float temp = 0;

        public MyGraphview(Context context, float[] values) {

            super(context);

            value_degree = new float[values.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                value_degree[i] = values[i];
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Random r;
            for (int i = 0; i < value_degree.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    r = new Random();
                    int color = Color.argb(100, r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256),
                            r.nextInt(256));
                    paint.setColor(color);
                    canvas.drawArc(rectf, 0, value_degree[i], true, paint);

                } else {
                    temp += value_degree[i - 1];
                    r = new Random();
                    int color = Color.argb(255, r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256),
                            r.nextInt(256));
                    paint.setColor(color);
                    canvas.drawArc(rectf, temp, value_degree[i], true, paint);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyGraphview1 extends View {
        private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        private float[] value_degree;
        RectF rectf = new RectF(170, 370, 330, 530);

        float temp = 0;

        public MyGraphview1(Context context, float[] values) {

            super(context);

            value_degree = new float[values.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                value_degree[i] = values[i];
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Random r;
            for (int i = 0; i < value_degree.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    r = new Random();
                    int color = Color.argb(100, r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256),
                            r.nextInt(256));
                    paint.setColor(color);
                    canvas.drawArc(rectf, 0, value_degree[i], true, paint);

                } else {
                    temp += value_degree[i - 1];
                    r = new Random();
                    int color = Color.argb(255, r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256),
                            r.nextInt(256));
                    paint.setColor(color);
                    canvas.drawArc(rectf, temp, value_degree[i], true, paint);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my result

[image: wrong output]

But Expected result is

[image: expected output]

What is wrong in my code friends. please help me. Thanks in advance.

if I remove the params so it would be

addView(view);
and remove Index

```
        MyGraphview graphview = new MyGraphview(this, values);
//      graphview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
//              LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        lv1.addView(graphview);
        MyGraphview1 graphview1 = new MyGraphview1(this, values1);
//      graphview1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
//              LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        lv1.addView(graphview1);
```

Then my output is:

[image]

Comment: This may be a simplified layout, but there is no need to have both a LinearLayout and RelativeLayout. You can remove one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks lot who all are trying to solve my problem friends. I have found solution with following modifications. I think the answer will be helpful to someone who searching solution for this problem friends. Because now I feel the last minute presser from our boss.

First my xml changes as per @Karan suggestions.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

then I override `onMeasure` method in both MyGraphview and MyGraphview1 classes as folling to set height as @Merlins suggestions.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            this.setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        }
```

width and height are

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
height /= 2;
```

then changes in `onCreate` method

```
LinearLayout lv1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
LinearLayout lv2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
values = calculateData(values);
values1 = calculateData(values1);

MyGraphview graphview = new MyGraphview(this, values);
MyGraphview1 graphview1 = new MyGraphview1(this, values1);

lv1.addView(graphview);
lv2.addView(graphview1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the params so it would be

```
lv1.addView(graphview);
lv1.addView(graphview1);
```

you don't need it in your case.

Update: now add the weight to 1 each.

```
graphview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1));
graphview1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
              LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1));
```

Comment: I agree, bad downvote. Have extra points to restore the natural balance of the Androidverse.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I might, calling `addView(view, 0)` will not replace any existing View.

Comment: @Sam Have you tried it? I haven't but based off of docs, when it doesn't say insert it will be replaced. I will try it later. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I did downvote due to misinformation. The integer parameter is only the insertion position which is zero indexed ... replacement does not occur.  Read the docs

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are setting the height and width of both child views to the linearlayout values.

You should use only **half the height** to fit both in ;)

**UPDATE**

Well you can use weights, like so:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            params.weight = 1.0f;

graphview.setLayoutParams(params);
graphview1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Or you could get the height from the lv1 params:

```
LinearLayour.LayoutParams lvparams = lv1.getLayoutParams();
int lvHeight = lvParams.height;
```

Then multiply that height by 0.5 and use it as your height argument in you view layout instead of WRAP_CONTENT

Comment: How can i achieve this friend. can you explain littile bit more.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you should add another linearlayout and add your addview to it
for eg...

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout lv1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
    LinearLayout lv2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
    values = calculateData(values);
    values1 = calculateData(values1);
    MyGraphview graphview = new MyGraphview(this, values);
    graphview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    lv1.addView(graphview, 0);
    MyGraphview1 graphview1 = new MyGraphview1(this, values1);
    graphview1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    lv2.addView(graphview1, 0);

}
```

and dont forget to add linearlayout in your xml...

Comment: you will get the required output...but i didnt know why it didnt work with single layout...